# JSON/cURL - Trying to decode results from GET request

Tags: php, json, curl

Here is my code `(CURL)`:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/DesktopModules/ProductDetail/API/ItemSuggestions/GetProductSuggestions?productId=433006&numPlacements=1&ItemType=product";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "ChosenSite=www; SportsDirect_AnonymousUserCurrency=GBP; language=en-GB");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
$collections = json_decode($result);

    foreach ($collections as $item) {
        $Title = $item->Products->Title;            

        echo $Title;
    }
```

With this code i receive blank screen, no results are printed.
All i want is to `echo` all the `Title` names of all products.

Where is my mistake, how can i achieve what i want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below code. It will help you definatly.

```
foreach ($collections as $row){
foreach ($row->Products as $item) {
    $Title = $item->Title;            

    echo $Title;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's because $item->Products is an array. You want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($collections as $item) {
    foreach($item->Products AS $product){
        $Title = $product->Title;            
        echo $Title;
    }
}
```